# Find maximum contiguous subarray sum whose subarray's first & last values are equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this question and could only come up with brute-force approach

```
Example - [1 9 -2 9 4 2 4]
Ans - [9 -2 9] = 16

Example - [9 -18 9 2 9]
Ans - 9+2+9 = 20

Example - [5,1,4,1,10,1,7]
Ans - 1+4+1+10+1 = 17
```

Comment: Was your brute force approach O(n^3)? If so, it can be easily reduced to O(n^2) by maintaining a prefix-sum array. The prefix sum array takes O(n) to precompute, but this would help you to find sum between any two indices in O(1). An alternative to prefix-sum array is to just maintain a variable to keep track of sum as you add or remove indices.

Comment: @Cherubim I solved the brute force approach in O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Kadane's algorithm but instead of single values, we need to add subarray sums. We can keep a record of the best starting index per value. Python code:

```py
def f(A):
  # Prefix sums
  ps = [0] * (len(A) + 1)
  for i in range(len(A)):
    ps[i] = A[i] + ps[i-1]

  # Map of value to its
  # best starting index.
  h = {}

  # Best overall sum
  best_sum = 0

  for i in range(len(A)):
    # We extend the interval by keeping the same
    # starting index; Otherwise, reset the starting
    # index.
    if (not A[i] in h) or (ps[i] - ps[h[A[i]] - 1] <= 0):
      h[A[i]] = i
    candidate = ps[i] - ps[h[A[i]] - 1] if i != h[A[i]] else 0
    best_sum = max(best_sum, candidate)
  
  return best_sum

As = [
  [1, 9, -2, 9, 4, 2, 4], # 16
  [9, -18, 9, 2, 9], # 20
  [5, 1, 4, 1, 10, 1, 7], # 17
  [1, 2, 3] # 0
]

for A in As:
  print(A)
  print(f(A))
  print('')
```